# What games does Shadowplay work on?

Tags: shadowplay

Does [Shadowplay](http://www.geforce.com/geforce-experience/shadowplay), a videogame specific tool for the recording of gameplay, work on "arbitrary games" or does it only support [the relatively few games supported by GeForce Experience](http://www.geforce.com/geforce-experience/supported-games)?

I suppose that, given a desktop GPU, you *could* record the desktop, and that would include any given game, so long as you were playing in windowed mode, and the window was top-most, and it was never moved, and you cropped the video afterwards to just the game area. But that's kind of an hassle, and the sound recording would also include sounds from other windows.

Comment: As I understand it, Shadowplay works with anything and everything that works in true fullscreen (not borderless window), and it still grabs the whole display - Steam notifications are still captured, for instance. They might've updated it since I last checked, though, so I'm just posting this as a comment.

Comment: @Pvt.Grichmann The newest ShadowPlay update added desktop capture to the lot (though desktop capture needs to be activated specifically), so ShadowPlay will work with pretty much anything now.

Comment: Yeah, I checked for updates almost immediately after leaving that comment. Felt pretty stupid. I'll give it a few more tests to see if something gets in the way of desktop capture or older versions of DirectX or OpenGL cause any problems.

Comment: I've used Shadowplay pretty extensively for my group's YouTube channel and it has worked for pretty much every PC game I've thrown at it - if it doesn't recognise the game or records 'black' or something, the 'desktop capture' setting has worded whether the game is fullscreen or windowed. I'm sure there are edge cases out there (might try and find some to & flesh out an answer later) but for the most part I've been surprised (and impressed) with the inherent compatibility even if their 'supported games' list is really small.